# In Visual Studio Code, there are many output log streams. How can I scan them all for an error message?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes Visual Studio code will issue a "toast" popup error message that lacks context, and the user must search the "OUTPUT" streams to find more information:

[image: so many output streams]

Is there a central place where these logs are maintained, such that I could just run `grep` or similar tools, rather than clicking through each of these drop-down entries?